# How to POST (upload) file to node.js from Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, file-upload, form-data

I am trying to upload a file via my nodejs backend. I have followed mutliple tutorials on how to do this and I have the backend working great.

I have tested my API via postman and it works as intended.

My issue seems to be on the front end but I cannot see how I am doing anything differently then the docs or tutorials say. Would truly appreciate any advice.

**HTML For Button**

```
<input type="file" style="display: inline-block;" (change)="onFileChange($event.target.files)" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".xlsx">
```

**onFileChange**

```js
  onFileChange(event: File[]) {
      this.commonAPIService.postFile(event[0]).subscribe(data => {
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

**Service**

```js
  postFile(fileToUpload: File) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileKey', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
    return this._http.post('/api/single', formData).pipe(
      map(() => {
        return true;
      }),
      catchError((err) => throwError(handleError(err)))
    );
  }
```

Currently I get the following error in my backend console:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token - in JSON at position 0
```

Comment: Can you show what is happening in the network console (browser)? Also, your upload url is relative, how are you routing this?

Comment: Great call! The issue was my standard http interceptor was adding content type of json. After fixing that it worked. Thanks!